# I'm trying to move a CSS element at will with a button, I tried to use offset and onlick did not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I want to move css items at will depending on a button or a function, actually I intend to increment them per pixel or depending on the scale, a percentage of pixels.

Anyway, I know the starting positions of the elements eg. top and left, I specify them, what I want is to be able to provide a new coordinate for the top/left at will like clicking a button eg. "moveByOnePixel"

I'm not sure if I am missing something huge; I think I have to use AJAX for live/dynamic

This is the basis of what I have assuming the div element with id #object exists and is currently located at top: 300px, left: 300px;

I want to move it to top: 301px; 301px; on one click, then the second click top: 302px; left: 302px; etc...

Part of this code isn't necessary, I was using the JQuery tutorial's code on offset

```
<script>

$( "*", document.body ).click(function( event ) {
  var offset = $( this ).offset();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $( "#result" ).text( this.tagName +
    " coords ( " + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + " )" );
});

function moveByOnePixel(){
var offset = $( #object ).offset();
var x = offset.left; 
var y = offset.top;
$( "#object" ).offset({ top: y+1, left: x+1 });
}
</script>

<button onclick="moveByOnePixel">move up</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

your example is close to a solution, so I'm providing one below that does the trick.  The big thing I noticed was that you didn't enclose `#object` in quotes (in the first line of your `moveByOnePixel()` function).

First, here's my general assumption of what the `#object` element would look like (just an example, obviously - the important part is that its `top` and `left` properties are 300px):

```
<div id="object" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; top: 300px; left: 300px;">hello</div>
<!-- added 'thebutton' as an ID to make the control easy to reference in JS -->
<button id="thebutton">move up</button>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
$('#thebutton').click(function( event ) {
  moveByOnePixel();
});

function moveByOnePixel(){
var offset = $('#object').offset(); // #object needs to be enclosed in quotes

// adding values to the top property does NOT move an element up, it moves it DOWN.  Hence, I am *subtracting* in this example  
  $('#object').offset({ top: offset.top - 1, left: offset.left - 1 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I chose his just because it was complete. Not really bias, consider me as an average lazy american consumer, I would rather have an iPhone than a Rapsberry Pi

Comment: Actually I will not choose. I appreciate both of your answers, it is one thing to give a person money, but another to teach them how to make more.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - glad you were able to get a solution to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Check this complete working example of yours.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Load your jquery file -->
<script src="../jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.obj{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
  top: 100px; left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="object" class="obj"></div>
<button onclick="moveByOnePixel()">move up</button>

<script>
function moveByOnePixel(){ 
  var offset = $( "#object" ).offset();
  var x = offset.left; 
  var y = offset.top;
  console.log(' X - '+x+' Y - '+y);
  $( "#object" ).offset({ top: y+1, left: x+1 });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I missed the part about "add your jquery file" nice... a pixel is ridiculously small it turns out so possibly doing percentage unless cut down on the time maybe it will be smoother that way like a higher framerate, anyway thank you